# Why does $-\sec(x) = 1/\cos(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why does $-\sec(x)$ become positive $1/\cos(x)$?
I thought that the negative would carry and it would be $-1/\cos(x)$.

Comment: Indeed, $$\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x};\quad -\sec x = -\frac{1}{\cos x}.$$

Comment: is it -secx or sec(-x)?

Answer (score 2):

You are right. 
Just by looking at the definition of $\sec(x)$, one can clearly see that
 $$\sec (x) = \frac{1}{\cos (x)}$$

But don't just take my word for it. Your equation itself will tell you if it's right or wrong.

$$ -\sec (x) = \frac{1}{\cos (x)} \implies -\frac{1}{\cos (x)} = \frac{1}{\cos (x)} \implies \large{-1 =1} \implies {\text{False}}$$

---

Now, there is a result similar to this which is true,
$$ \sec (-x) = \frac{1}{\cos(-x)} = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$

Why did that happen? Because $ \cos(-x) = \cos(x)$.

Again don't just take my word for it. 
I can prove it using the identity $\cos(A \pm B) = \cos(A)\times\cos(B) \mp \sin(A)\times\sin(B)$.
$$\cos(-x) = \cos (0-x) = \cos 0\times\cos x + \sin 0\times\sin x = 1\times\cos x + 0\times\sin x = \cos x$$

---

Never confuse $\sec(-x)$ with $-\sec(x)$. Always remember that
$$ \sec(-x) = +\sec(x) \quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R} $$

$\ddot\smile$ Hope this helps

Comment: You wrote $1/\cos(-x) = -1/\cos(x)$ which is wrong.

Comment: @TMM: It's because $\LaTeX$ is numbing my mind. Sorry and thank you for the correction.